# Can't check if a table exist in QT MYSQL

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtsql

I'm trying to check if a table exist in a schema for QMYSQL inside QT framework.
I have connected the MySQL server and it can create a table, but NOT check if a table exist.

This is the code for checking if a table exist

```
query.exec("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + "(ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY)");
QStringList tables = this->qSqlDatabase.tables();
qDebug() << "Table name: " + table_name;
for(int i = 0; i < tables.length(); i++)
    qDebug() << tables[i];
qDebug() << tables.length();
if(tables.contains(table_name))
```

The if-statement does not run and the output is:

```
"Table name: table0"
 0
```

In this case `table_name = "table0"`. But why does this happening?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: does that query.exec(...) return true or false?

Comment: and what last error is? https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#lastError

Comment: @V.K. it retrurns false.

Comment: @MrYui so it is clear that the problem is in the very first line. now check the last error.

Comment: btw. it seem sthat mySQL syntax for creating primary key is a bit different than yours. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.ASP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this line:

```
query.exec("CREATE TABLE " + table_name + " (ID BIGINT, PRIMARY KEY (ID));");
```

Comment: But creating a table works. But looking of there is a table that has been created, does not work.

Comment: By the way. I have solved this issue by just creating a table and don't care if the table already exist. Because QT handels that problem. Did not know that.

Comment: you wrote that this line returns false so it obviously does not work in your original code.

Comment: Oh sorry, did not understand directly. Yes, it returns true, but if I check if there are tables avaiable, then till will return 0.